# VBA code to display newest email with keyword in the subject

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm working on a VBA code to display only the newest email with the keyword of a selected cell. All those emails (including the emails I sent or received from other people) are filed a specific outlook folder "Inbox/abc/def". Below are the codes I have come up with, but it only displays the oldest.

```
Sub DisplayNewestEmail()
Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox").Folders("abc").Folders("def")

fol.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

For Each mi In fol.Items
            If InStr(mi.Subject, ActiveCell.Value) > 0 Then
                mi.Display
                Exit Sub
            End If
Next mi
Set ol = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing
Set fol = Nothing

End Sub
```

I also have tried changing the code of `fol.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True` to `fol.Items.Sort "[Received]", True` or `fol.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"`, but it still only displays the oldest email.

Can someone please tell me how to display the newest email only? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the following code to sort items in the collection:

```
fol.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
```

Your changes are not preserved when you get a new collection instance by using the following code:

```
For Each mi In fol.Items
```

If you want to preserve the sorting order when looping through items you need to declare an instance of the `Outlook.Items` class and use it for sorting and then looping over it. For example:

```
Dim itemsCollection as Outlook.Items

Set itemsCollection = fol.Items

itemsCollection.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

For Each mi In itemsCollection
```

But a better yet solution is to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to get items that correspond to the specified search criteria. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)